# Create array of parent element's text based on child element's string match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to search a massive member list (1200+) and find which of my admins added each member. I want the console to return an array of the names of all the members that were added by X, where X is the admin's name. That way I can compile a spreadsheet to keep track of which members were added by corresponding admin.

Example **HTML** I'm working with.

```
<div class="_6a _5u5j _6b">
  <div class="fsl fwb fcb"><a href="">Jessica Smith</a></div>
  <div class="_5aj7">
    <div class="_4bl9">
      <div class="_17tq">Model at Model/Actress</div>
      <div class="fsm fwn fcg">Joined
        <br>Added by Jane Doe <abbr title="Sunday, July 17, 2016 at 1:29pm" data-utime="1468772964" class="timestamp"><span class="timestampContent">about 4 months ago</span></abbr></div>
    </div>
    <div class="_4bl7 mrm"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="_6a _5u5j _6b">
  <div class="fsl fwb fcb"><a href="">Robyn Stevens</a></div>
  <div class="_5aj7">
    <div class="_4bl9">
      <div class="_17tq">No Job</div>
      <div class="fsm fwn fcg">Joined
        <br>Added by Jane Doe <abbr title="Sunday, July 17, 2016 at 1:29pm" data-utime="1468772964" class="timestamp"><span class="timestampContent">about 2 months ago</span></abbr></div>
    </div>
    <div class="_4bl7 mrm"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="_6a _5u5j _6b">
  <div class="fsl fwb fcb"><a href="">Sarah West</a></div>
  <div class="_5aj7">
    <div class="_4bl9">
      <div class="_17tq">Entertainer</div>
      <div class="fsm fwn fcg">Joined
        <br>Added by Jane Doe <abbr title="Sunday, July 17, 2016 at 1:29pm" data-utime="1468772964" class="timestamp"><span class="timestampContent">about 3 months ago</span></abbr></div>
    </div>
    <div class="_4bl7 mrm"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the **jQuery** I'm trying to execute in the console

```
$("div.fsm:contains('Jane Doe')").find("div.fsl a").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
})
```

But I'm not making any headway here. Here's a fiddle I'm playing around in https://jsfiddle.net/w9vfq62r/3/ any help to get this fiddle example working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want a generic query instead of hard coding the admin name and find?

Comment: Ideally yes that would be great

Comment: Yeah, I am doing this, few secs :-)

Comment: Okay, please check. I have given below a generic solution. You can test this with many admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, which will parse all the admins nicely and append the corresponding members to them into the admin array.

Updated with timestamp as well.

```js
var admins = {};
var refText = 'Added by';
$('div.fsm').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var addedByText = self.text().replace('\n', ' ').replace(/\s{2,}/, ' ');
    var startIndex = addedByText.indexOf(refText) + refText.length;
    var admin = $.trim(addedByText.substring(startIndex, addedByText.indexOf('about')));
    var member = self.closest('._6a').find('div.fsl a').text();
  
    if(!admins[admin]) {
      admins[admin] = [];
    }
  
    admins[admin].push(member);
    admins[admin].push(self.find('abbr').attr('title'));
});

console.log(admins);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="_6a _5u5j _6b">
  <div class="fsl fwb fcb"><a href="">Jessica Smith</a></div>
  <div class="_5aj7">
    <div class="_4bl9">
      <div class="_17tq">Model at Model/Actress</div>
      <div class="fsm fwn fcg">Joined
        <br>Added by Jane Doe <abbr title="Sunday, July 17, 2016 at 1:29pm" data-utime="1468772964" class="timestamp"><span class="timestampContent">about 4 months ago</span></abbr></div>
    </div>
    <div class="_4bl7 mrm"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="_6a _5u5j _6b">
  <div class="fsl fwb fcb"><a href="">Robyn Stevens</a></div>
  <div class="_5aj7">
    <div class="_4bl9">
      <div class="_17tq">No Job</div>
      <div class="fsm fwn fcg">Joined
        <br>Added by Jane Doe <abbr title="Sunday, July 17, 2016 at 1:29pm" data-utime="1468772964" class="timestamp"><span class="timestampContent">about 2 months ago</span></abbr></div>
    </div>
    <div class="_4bl7 mrm"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="_6a _5u5j _6b">
  <div class="fsl fwb fcb"><a href="">Sarah West</a></div>
  <div class="_5aj7">
    <div class="_4bl9">
      <div class="_17tq">Entertainer</div>
      <div class="fsm fwn fcg">Joined
        <br>Added by Jane Doe <abbr title="Sunday, July 17, 2016 at 1:29pm" data-utime="1468772964" class="timestamp"><span class="timestampContent">about 3 months ago</span></abbr></div>
    </div>
    <div class="_4bl7 mrm"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is amazing!!! One final request, would it be possible to grab the added date/time from the `<abbr>` title attribute? And list it next to each member in the array? So like

`{
  "Jane Doe": [
    "Jessica Smith", "Sunday, July 17, 2016 at 1:29pm"
    "Robyn Stevens", "Sunday, July 17, 2016 at 1:29pm"
    "Sarah West", "Sunday, July 17, 2016 at 1:29pm"
  ]
}`

Comment: Sure, will add now

Comment: @LordTubington Its quite fun actually once you started play with it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.fsm:contains('Jane Doe')").each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).closest("._6a").find("div.fsl a").text();
    console.log(txt);
});
```

Filter required divs, then get wrapper by `closest`, then get text of link

Comment: Worked in my fiddle, but when I tried to use it in the real environment I got the following error:

`Uncaught Error: <![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.","div.fsm:contains('Jane Doe'')"]]]>`

Comment: Can you reproduce code, which generate this error, on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Made it as function

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/thefto_dev/w9vfq62r/5/)

```
var memberss = getMembers("Jane Doe"); // function call to get array of members
alert(memberss);

function getMembers(adminName){
  var members = [];
  $('div.fsm:contains("'+adminName+'")').each(function() {
    var aMember = $(this).closest('._6a').find('.fsl a').text();
    members.push(aMember);
  });
  return members;
}
```